# A small confusion about topics

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am new to ros, I See people always use cmd_vel topic for geometry msgs. My confusion is, what is the reason of always using cmd_vel? Can't we use other topic name? Or there are some existing topics like msg, such as ros have existing msg type like Twist, odom, pose etc. If ros 2 also have some existing topics, what are they? how to find them? (Sorry for bad English).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370984/a-small-confusion-about-topics/) by [Momit](https://answers.ros.org/users/69289/momit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-04**:
I didn't get the second part of your question. ('or there are .....')

**Comment by [Momit](https://answers.ros.org/users/69289/momit/) on 2021-02-06**:
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, there's a small correction. People usually used `cmd_vel` topic for `[geometry_msgs/Twist]` messages.

We can use any topic name we want. Using the name `cmd_vel` is sort of a ROS convention.

---

Originally posted by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) with karma: 310 on 2021-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

controllers subscribe to /cmd_vel to read their velocity command.
you can use whatever topic name you want, but the controller is most likely not subscribed to the topicname you came up with.
You can view all the topics with  `rostopic list` as described in the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics).

---

Originally posted by [crnewton](https://answers.ros.org/users/59954/crnewton/) with karma: 71 on 2021-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1